# strange behavior with asp.net text box when made read only

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a asp.net page - it renders a number of custom controls, within the main page - I have a asp.net Textbox - in certain cases it has to be editable in others it has to be read only.  For the most part it is all working as expected.  There is a small bug I am having difficulty with.

[image]

So in my Previous Year column the values rendering should only be 1, 2, 3, 0 - etc - as you can see for some reason when rendering the markup it creates this markup:

```
<td id="ctl00_ctl00_PartContentPlaceHolderMain_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctrlComparison_ctrlComparisonCars1_ctl06">
                        <input name="ctl00$ctl00$PartContentPlaceHolderMain$ContentPlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctrlComparison$ctrlComparisonCars1$tbPreviousNoManualCars" type="text" value="1" disabled="disabled" id="ctl00_ctl00_PartContentPlaceHolderMain_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctrlComparison_ctrlComparisonCars1_tbPreviousNoManualCars" class="tbPreviousNumber ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="width:50px;display:none;"><span>1</span><span>1</span>                     
                    </td>
```

So the problem being the double span that is generated.  In my main page that renders this control I want to do something like:

```
        var test = $("#ctl00_ctl00_PartContentPlaceHolderMain_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctrlComparison_ctrlComparisonCars1_PreviousNoManualCars").children().find('span').val();
        alert(test);
```

However my alert says undefined. Is it possible to remove one of these spans using something similar to the above?

Also is there a better way to get the id that will be rendered - I have just pulled the exact one on screen from Developer Tools just for testing to try and get this working.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used val(), but it should be **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)** , since it is not a input element, its `span`

also use **[next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/)**

```
 var test = $("#ctl00_ctl00_PartContentPlaceHolderMain_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctrlComparison_ctrlComparisonCars1_tbPreviousNumberNoManualCars")
    .next('span').text();
    alert(test);
```

Comment: Hi Murali - thanks for your reply - I used the following - $("#ctl00_ctl00_PartContentPlaceHolderMain_ContentPlaceHolderMain_ctl00_ctrlExposureComparison_ctrlExposureComparisonCanada1_tbPreviousNumberPrivatePassengers").next('span').remove(); - which works in that it removes the span and the data in table is correct - is there a better way to get the id from the control - rather than copying what I found from the rendered markup

Comment: @KOL, glad it works. You can access the element other than id, incase if you cant predict. You can access it using `class` & `attriute` depends on your situation. Check the `jquery selector` for more detail. For now you can use `$("input[id*='tbPreviousNumberNoManualCars']")` this says input with id contains the word `tbPreviousNumberNoManualCars`